# Xamarin UITest (.NET 4.8 class library) with reference to .NET standard libraries / MAUI libs

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, xamarin.uitest

I have a legacy project of Xamarin UITests that I shall bring over into MAUI world. Xamarin UITests are .NET 4.8. The UITest project references several libraries that are .NET standard or MAUI libraries. The IDE says rightfully, that they are not compatible.
Is there a good approach to make this happen in a sensible way?

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are able to run Xamarin.UITest on .Net 6, you may have to convert your project over to .Net 6 to be able to run your legacy project within a MAUI project. I have done this and it has worked for me pretty well I am going through the transition of moving all my legacy Xamarin.UITest projects that are on .Net Framework 4.8 over to .Net 6 to keep the project alive.